# Star Rating System With Checkboxes and PHP backend

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to make a star rating system in html with checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked, the previous are checked and the others are unchecked.

The result will be POSTed to my php code backend.

Here's my current html:

```
<span class="star-rating">
   <!--RADIO 1-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="1" name="item" id="radio1">
        <label class="label_item" for="radio1"> <img src="label.png" style="width:30px;height:28px"> </label>

    <!--RADIO 2-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="2" name="item2" id="radio2">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio2"> <img src="label.png" style="width:30px;height:28px"> </label>

      <!--RADIO 3-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="3" name="item3" id="radio3">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio3"> <img src="label.png" style="width:30px;height:28px"> </label>


      <!--RADIO 4-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="4" name="item4" id="radio4">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio4"> <img src="label.png" style="width:30px;height:28px"> </label>

      <!--RADIO 5-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="5" name="item5" id="radio5">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio5"> <img src="label.png" style="width:30px;height:28px"> </label>
</span>
```

Comment: do you want this done immediately in the browser, or after the form is submitted and rebuilt?

Comment: @MarcB, it is a star rating as can be read in the span class. I think it is client side only.

Comment: I think this link has pretty much what you need: http://rog.ie/blog/css-star-rater

Comment: I want it done in the browser, so that if they select checkbox four then one, two and three are selected.

Comment: @MauricioMoraes I want to create a star system but I what to do with using php is I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Jquery in your html and this simple javascript code might do just what you want.

```js
$('.star-rating input').click( function(){
    starvalue = $(this).attr('value');
    
    // iterate through the checkboxes and check those with values lower than or equal to the one you selected. Uncheck any other.
    for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
        if (i <= starvalue){
            $("#radio" + i).prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $("#radio" + i).prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="star-rating">
   <!--RADIO 1-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="1" name="item" id="radio1">
        <label class="label_item" for="radio1"> &#9734 </label>

    <!--RADIO 2-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="2" name="item2" id="radio2">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio2"> &#9734 </label>

      <!--RADIO 3-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="3" name="item3" id="radio3">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio3"> &#9734 </label>


      <!--RADIO 4-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="4" name="item4" id="radio4">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio4"> &#9734 </label>

      <!--RADIO 5-->
    <input type='checkbox' class="radio_item" value="5" name="item5" id="radio5">
    <label class="label_item" for="radio5"> &#9734 </label>
</span>
```

Obs: The html code is the same as yours. I've just replaced the images by stars as the links were broken.

Obs2: When you post this to your php, you will receive all checked inputs. Your php code will have to be smart and take the highest value it receives. This should not be difficult.

Obs3: The stars should behave as radio-buttons and not checkboxes. The workaround from Obs2 means that your backend code has too much knowledge of what is happening on the interface. This is a more advanced tip, but take that in consideration in the future.

**EXTRA**

To include this code in your app, you have some options:

**OPTION 1** (jQuery from google CDN and javascript code on script tag)

Put this in your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.star-rating input').click( function(){
        starvalue = $(this).attr('value');

        // iterate through the checkboxes and check those with values lower than or equal to the one you selected. Uncheck any other.
        for(i=0; i<=5; i++){
            if (i <= starvalue){
                $("#radio" + i).prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                $("#radio" + i).prop('checked', false);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

**OPTION 2** (better: jQuery from CDN and javascript file included with php):

Include jQuery as above and put the javascript code in a file: star_rating.js, then include that file with php include command.

Comment: This is fantasic man. I'm new to programming in php and javascrip. How do I include it in my html file?

Comment: @DerekJoseph, I added this to the answer.

Comment: @DerekJoseph, Remember that, after choosing the ammount of stars, you will have to submit it. (a simple form around it and a button will do)

Comment: `$(this).nextAll('input').attr('checked', false)` & `$(this).prevAll('input').addBack().attr('checked', true)`

Comment: @DJDavid98 your code works for the first iteration, but if you click on the fifth star, the, on the first , and then on other star again, it doesn't fill the other stars.